# Android: Showing Detail on TextView click

Tags: android

I have a layout where I have FAQs. I have a textView beneath every question which shows the answer upon clicking the Question.

[image: This is the page layout]

The problem is the gap which the innvisible TextView has. I dont want that gap between every question. I have looked for a way on the net but couldn't find anything beneficial. Can someone guide me what I need to look for?

Comment: please read documentation for view visibility https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: Yes I just read it. I feel so stupid that I didn't read it before! thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Visibility.GONE` to have no gap.

Comment: oh thanks! that worked! didn't know about this one!

Comment: No problem @JiyaKhan

Answer (score 0):

> `Visibility.GONE`     Will remove the view from its allocated area.
>
> `Visibility.INVISIBLE` Just hide the view it really exists back there.

Comment: vote up and tick mark is better way of saying thanks to whom who helps you.

Comment: @JiyaKhan my answer was first so it is not fair

Comment: sorry @SohailZahid Maciej answer was first and it did solve my issue. Maciej Im sorry I am newbie here so i thought i can accept multiple answers :D my bad!